# Javax.persistence.PersistenceException:Invalid persistence.xml

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa

I am a newbie of JPA and I'm working with JPA in Netbeans.
I have an error on my persistence.xml file but I don't know how to solve it:

### Error Msgs:

```
35940 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.6.Final
[2014-01-24 10:00:28,025] ERROR: Unable to prepare PXS
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.tps.persistence.TPSPersister.<init>(TPSPersister.java:119)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.tps.persistence.TPSPersister.getInstance(TPSPersister.java:127)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.pxs.necontrol.nce.NeControlEngine.prepare(NeControlEngine.java:109)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.pxs.PXSComponent.prepare(PXSComponent.java:273)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.CCSMain.prepareComponents(CCSMain.java:202)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.CCSMain.startServer(CCSMain.java:446)
    at org.astri.ims.ccs.CCSMain.main(CCSMain.java:571)
[2014-01-24 10:00:28,027] ERROR: Failed to prepare the component:Proxy Services
```

I have tired to change the version from 2.1 to 2.0 as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743886/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-invalid-persistence-xml) said.
However it's not work for me.
Here's my persistence.xml file:

### Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Ent_ccserverPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>org.entitymodel.Clientassociation</class>
         a lots of entities here...
<class>org.entitymodel.Ipset</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ims?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypswd"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
</properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have tried changing my persistence.xml to :(as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176545/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-jpahibernate) mentioned.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" 
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="Ent_ccserverPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>org.entitymodel.Clientassociation</class>
  Some entities here...
<class>org.entitymodel.Ipset</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ims?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypswd"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
</properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But in vain.

My persistence.xml is produced by Netbeans, and I have tried build this file in another project and it was working fine, so I have no idea what's the problem.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the closing tags of the persistence XML file.

add

```
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

to the end of the file and you should be good to go!.

Comment: Sorry that was an edit error.
There are closing tags in my persistence.xml.
But I lost them while edit the question(Though I did paste it)

Comment: You might need to add the hibernate dependency to maven. <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thank you Sparticles,
I found change version to 2.0 is work. Just because I forgot compile my project and run it, so it runs with original persistence.xml.
However, thank you very much!