# Intellij Ultimate not executing jpa-ql query

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have Intellij-Idea Ultimate version 14.1.4, and I was trying to [execute a JPA-QL query with the console](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/jpa-console-tool-window.html).

I tried a simple one and I had an error I report below. Is this some misconfiguration on my end or a bug?

```
[2015-08-24 14:43:59] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'stream' of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.loadTextAndClose must not be null
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.loadTextAndClose(FileUtil.java)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.loadJpaTemplate(JpaEngine.java:241)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.createPersistenceXmlText(JpaEngine.java:151)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.createTemporaryJpaConfig(JpaEngine.java:207)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.access$000(JpaEngine.java:61)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine$1.compute(JpaEngine.java:143)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine$1.compute(JpaEngine.java:136)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$1.run(DumbService.java:87)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$2.compute(DumbService.java:123)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$2.compute(DumbService.java:117)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:117)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:84)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.createTemporaryConfig(JpaEngine.java:136)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.ensureInitialized(JpaEngine.java:97)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngine.createQuery(JpaEngine.java:104)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngineBase.executeQueryInner(JpaEngineBase.java:166)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngineBase.access$000(JpaEngineBase.java:56)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngineBase$1.compute(JpaEngineBase.java:128)
        at com.intellij.jpa.engine.JpaEngineBase$1.compute(JpaEngineBase.java:123)
        at com.intellij.database.console.AbstractEngine$4.compute(AbstractEngine.java:179)
        at com.intellij.database.console.AbstractEngine$4.compute(AbstractEngine.java:174)
        at com.intellij.database.console.AbstractEngine$3.run(AbstractEngine.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I opened a ticket and Jetbrains responded, that the fix is part of IDEA 15. The prior error does not occur any more, but now IDEA doesn't like my persistence.xml (java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml) :-/

Comment: Note : A very useful hint from ItelliJ support : Would you please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/21115437/2000323 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21229236/2000323 . Please double check that your persistence and hibernate versions which you are using in project are compatible.

Also check that your persistence.xml is correctly formed xml http://stackoverflow.com/a/19744880/2000323 .


Also, I had to increase memory (idea64.exe.vmoptions) and start the proper version (idea64 instead of 32bit version). After that, stuff ran fine.
Crucial Info : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21115437/2000323